# How to read in JSON so each element of dict/hash is a new row in dataframe?

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm attempting to read a large dataset written in JSON into a dataframe.

a minimal working example of this dataframe:

```
{"X":{"sex":"Male","age":57,"BMI":"19.7"},"XX":{"BMI":"30.7","age":44,"sex":"Female"},"XXX":{"age":18,"sex":"Female","BMI":"22.3"},"XXXX":{"sex":"Male","age":29,"BMI":"25.7"},"ZZZ":{"sex":"Male","age":61,"BMI":"40.5"}}
```

However, the dataset is not being read correctly, as it should have about 10,999 elements, and I'm only getting 1.

The JSON is a hash/dict where each element should be a new row.

I've tried

```
df = spark.read.option.json("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/xyz/data.json")

df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/xyz/data.json")
```

I've also tried `inferSchema`, but this doesn't interpret the schema even close to correctly: I still get 1 row.

and made a custom schema, where each field is a sub-key of each row.

e.g.

```
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField('Admission_Date', StringType(), True),
    StructField('BMI', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('latest_date', StringType(), True),...
...
    StructField('sex', StringType(), True),True)
])
```

and then load with the custom schema:

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").schema(custom_schema).json("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/xyz/data.json")
```

but this *again* yields a single row.

How can I load this JSON so that every key is considered a single row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create array column from all the dataframe columns, explode it and star expand the resulting struct column :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select(
    F.explode(F.array(*df.columns)).alias("rows")
).select("rows.*")

df1.show()

#+----+---+------+
#| BMI|age|   sex|
#+----+---+------+
#|19.7| 57|  Male|
#|30.7| 44|Female|
#|22.3| 18|Female|
#|25.7| 29|  Male|
#|40.5| 61|  Male|
#+----+---+------+
```